# Entity Framework: ChildCollection item removal

Tags: entity-framework-4

Given the relationship:

> Person 1 -- * TelephoneNumber
>
> (A person has 0, 1 or more TelephoneNumber entities)

And my integration test:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void DeleteTelephoneNumberAndSavePersonTest()
    {
        Person person;
        using (SopEntities sopEntities = EntitiesFactory.Create(Properties.Resources.ConnectionString))
        {
            PeopleRepository target = new PeopleRepository(sopEntities);
            person = target.GetPerson(7);
            Assert.IsTrue(person.TelephoneNumbers.Any());
            Assert.AreEqual("DeleteTelephoneNumberAndSavePersonTest", person.TelephoneNumbers.Single().Number);
            person.TelephoneNumbers.Remove(person.TelephoneNumbers.Single());
            target.SavePerson(person);

            Person savedPerson = target.GetPerson(7);
            Assert.IsFalse(savedPerson.TelephoneNumbers.Any());
        }
    }
```

Which obtains an already created (and I know this to be true) Person (ID=7) with a single TelephoneNumber in its TelephoneNumbers collection. This works fine.

I then Remove the TelephoneNumber as part of my test.

And save it, which uses the following code:

```
    public Person SavePerson(Person person)
        {
            if (person == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("person");

            
            Person existingPerson= SopEntities.People.Include("EmailAddresses").Include("TelephoneNumbers").Include("WebResources").SingleOrDefault(q => q.ID==person.ID);
// NOTE: The existingPerson ALREADY has the TelephoneNumber removed, even though retrieved from the DB again. WHY IS THIS?

// snip: collection reconciliation code

            SopEntities.SaveChanges();
            return existingPerson;
        }
```

I don't want to distract this post with the reconciliation of in-memory to persisted collections at this point, but would like to draw your attention to the trieval of existingPerson. This person already has the TelephoneNumber removed from its TelephoneNumbers collection when I debug this through.

The reason for this is that it is within the same Entities context in the TestMethod. If I create a new context between loading the TelephoneNumber and removing the item, the retrieved Person does have the expected TelephoneNumber in the TelephoneNumbers collection for removal in due course.

EntityFramework is clearly caching the change and "projecting" (for want of a better word) the change into the internal contexts. I do not want this to happen.

How can I prevent this behaviour? ie. when I ask for database content, I WANT database content not EF's impression of DB content.

Comment: To me your question looks like a XY problem: You want to achieve X and try to solve it via Y, but Y doesn't work and you ask why Y doesn't work and how you can change Y to make it work. If you ask X (explain, what's the purpose to load the unchanged person in the `Save` method) you might get better answers.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I wasn't too clear in excluding the distracting elements of the code. It *looks* like I am returning existingPerson from the SopEntities result, but part of the code that is missing is I am updating the returned object in the event of the entity already existing.

This is not, however, the problem. The problem is that removing a TelephoneNumber from the Person.TelephoneNumbers collection and then submitting it removes it from the ObjectContext, so I cannot reconcile the differences during save. 

I suspect my repository pattern is not up to scratch. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load the person in this line...

```
Person existingPerson= SopEntities.People....
    .SingleOrDefault(q => q.ID==person.ID);
```

...with disabled change tracking (use `AsNoTracking()` for `DbContext` and `MergeOption.NoTracking` for `ObjectContext`) to avoid that EF tries to attach the entity to the context where you already modified it.

This might be useless if you want to use the object returned from `SavePerson` for change tracking and want to have it attached to the context. EF does not allow to have two attached objects with the same key and it will return the already attached object including all modifications you already applied to the entity.

I don't know what you want to achieve. It looks a bit like your `SavePerson` method is supposed to return the "previous" person (the person in the state before you modified it). If so, another approach would be to (deep) clone the object before you start to modify it and return the clone.